# Is there a process to create one CSV from an SSIS package containing multiple queries?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

Is there a process to create one CSV file from an SSIS package containing multiple queries? 
I have a request for a report. However, the data on the report would come from multiple queries from different tables. See below for the report layout.

[image: ReportLayOut]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by having several data sources in a SSIS dataflow and using the UNION ALL transformation in SSIS to union the data before it reaches the single CSV destination component.[image: This is how it looks with mulitple sources and the union transformation]

Comment: Can I do this even though the Columns and Rows are not the same size in each tablix on the report?

Comment: Yes, in the union all transformation dialog you can add columns by typing a name in the left most column and then map them as you want from the different input sources, choosing <ignore> in the drop down list for the ones that shouldn't be mapped to anything in the result

Answer (score 0):

You can create three different `dataflow` tasks, where you can set the same CSV as 'destination'. But do not forget to check the option called *"Overwrite data in file"* `unchecked`.

Basically it is flat-file, so no indexing problem can occur. But when creating Connection string for each, will be required your sample formatted file(as a destination). So it will take each field by default.